# Fitting a prolate cycloid between two points (to a certain length)

Tags: geometry, rotations, parametric, cycloid

I need to draw a prolate cycloid such that it fits a certain length l, and has an integer number of wavelengths. I have these equations for the prolate cycloid:

$$x = h\cos(t+\phi)\cos\theta+at\sin\theta$$
$$y = h(\sin(t+\phi)+1)$$
$$t: 0 ..2\pi n$$ 
where n is the number of wavelengths.

h here is the amplitude of wave (half the height of the whole figure). a, I believe, is related to where the cutoff point happens in the wave, not quite sure on this one though. I am currently just assigning a to be $\frac{3}{5}h$ which is giving me fairly alright figures. Varying $\theta$ seems to be varying the length of the graph.

Now, how do I set the rotation angle, $\theta$, such that the figure fits in a certain length, l, with a certain number of wavelengths, n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
x(0)=h\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
x(2\pi n)=h\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)+2\pi na\sin\theta.
$$
We want $x(2\pi n)-x(0)=l$, that is $2\pi na\sin\theta=l$, whence:
$$
\sin\theta={l\over 2\pi na}.
$$

Comment: This worked amazingly! Thank you so much